# When should Bee Balm bloom in Zone 6 (it did not bloom last year)?

Tags: flowers, plant-care, flowering, perennials

Two years ago we planted some bee balm. We trimmed it back in early March last year and it never bloomed, though the plant was otherwise healthy and bushy.

We trimmed it back again this year. Is there a deficiency that may have caused the bee balm to not bloom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monarda (bee balm) likes damp, enriched soil, but also likes a lot of sun. They often don't flower in their first year, but I'd have expected flowers in its second year, certainly. If it dries out frequently, you may not get flowers, and depending on which variety you're growing, it might not be getting enough sun. If the soil it's growing in is poor and thin, then it might be wise to mulch with something humus rich (well rotted manure or garden compost). Most varieties should be in flower for most of the summer.

Comment: My problem is probably moisture because it gets plenty of sun throughout the day but the soil tends to dry out quickly with the way the weather gets in the summer.

Comment: @artuhfakt - that's the problem I always have with these - full sun means it dries out so no flowers, shade means moist but not enough sun. The only answer is to make a special effort to keep them well watered during hot/dry spells.